# X-Plane 10 doesn't run due to "annot find autorun program"

Tags: installation, wine

I am trying to install X-Plane 10 GLOBAL (I 1000 version DVD VERSION X-Plane 10) on Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) and I am getting the following message:

```
Error autorunning software  Cannot find autorun program
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to install a Windows version on wine?
X-plane 10 GLOBAL includes Windows, Mac and *Linux* versions.

If you have global scenery on your DVDs, but you don't have linux installer,  you may download installer for linux here:

> http://www.x-plane.com/downloads/x-plane_10_installer-updater/

Before istallation starts, make sure you have:

> libopenal1 (Which basically is an OpenAL library)

Installation will require internet connection. After installing X-plane, start x-plane installer/updater and choose option `Add/Remove Scenery`, follow guides and insert the discs.

After installing scenery you may update your X-plane using X-plane installer if you want.

To unlock X-plane demo you need to  insert the first disc in your DVD drive. If you have any joysticks/yokes/etc. plug them before loading X-plane. Then load x-plane and have fun.

This link may help you:

> http://wiki.x-plane.com/Category:Linux

Comment: BTW, If you want to use a 64-bit version of app, check install betas. The newest 10.20 beta has a separated 64-bit version.

Comment: BTW, you need to run Installer with sudo admin rights

Comment: Make sure to check the X-plane wiki. It has a Linux Installation section at http://wiki.x-plane.com/Linux_Installation_Walkthrough